# How to Protect melamine panel dining table from water and wear

Tags: mdf, water-protection, physical-protection

I have a dining table from Mobili fiver with the following material specification:
https://www.mobilifiver.com/eu/media/akeneo_connector/media_files/S/c/Scheda_tecnica_materiali_ebe9.pdf

How can I protect it against water damage and regular wear and tear. I want some kind of clear/non-glossy finish. I thought polyurethane *could* work, since it does well for my other plywood furniture. But I am not sure. Any recommendations?

Comment: I probably don't understand perfectly, but melamine IS the protection.. the only thing I can think of which would need some sort of protection is the "endgrain", i.e. cut edges - I saw a few water damaged particleboard edges, but mostly in bathroom furniture - kitchen table from melamine boards should be fine as long as the edges of the table are properly sealed with plastic strips or iron-on edges. As for wear and tear - melamine is quite durable, I don't think there is any reason to put additional finish on top of melamine.. Or maybe I really didn't understand what you mean..

Answer (score 4):

As the Comment from @JanSpurny says, melamine IS the protection. If you think about it, if this is sold as tabletop material it should already be suitable for this application. As the PDF you linked to says:

*"Melamine surfaces are among the most resistant of those used in the furniture and furnishing industry."*

Melamine (or more accurately, melamine laminate) is rather famous for how tough it can be — amply demonstrated by the thick melamine-coated chipboard/particleboard now used so commonly for kitchen countertops. Assuming they're not abused, these can withstand *decades* of hot plates, food and water spills, and regular cleaning (even multiple times a day) with almost no sign of wear.

The Achilles's heel of this material generally is the joins between the face laminate and the edging material, so be careful along the arrises and the corners. Other than not cleaning using anything abrasive the only particular care I'd take personally would be to make sure I didn't leave liquids puddled right at the edge.